# Microsoft access token issue invalid_grant Trace ID and correlation id issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am providing followings details to the endpoint using

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token
content_type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type : authorization_code
client_id: correct_client_id
client_secret: correct_client_secret
code: valid_code
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: bea03858-4d32-4d88-a1b6-33b7fa2e0d01\r\nCorrelation ID: ab097b2b-4f83-4b15-b909-36a4a8aba5ab\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-10 14:43:36Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-02-10 14:43:36Z",
    "trace_id": "bea03858-4d32-4d88-a1b6-33b7fa2e0d01",
    "correlation_id": "ab097b2b-4f83-4b15-b909-36a4a8aba5ab",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

Even though, we are giving  `grant_type` as `authorization_code`, it still is giving error. It is really frustrating to see this error and find out real cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your message looks wrong in a couple of places:

- Form URL encoded means ampersand characters between fields as in [this example](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/)
- You seem to be missing parameters such as redirect_uri which are required for security purposes

How exactly are you sending the request and what technology are you using? It is always recommended to use a library - I may be able to recommend one for you.